# Copy zip files from NFS share to multiple servers

Tags: ansible

Just started using Ansible and Linux (CentOs&RedHat). I have 7 zip files on a NFS share that I want to copy over to my managed servers.

I use:

```
- name: copy install files
  copy:
    src: /public/
    dest: "/tmp/INSTALL_{{ ansible_fqdn }}/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - p1.zip
    - p2.zip
    - p3.zip
```

I have a NFS share on //192.168.0.13/public with public access for everybody. Firewalld is stopped & disabled.

When I run the above I get "ERROR! A worker was found in a dead state"

Do I need to first mount the NFS share in the playbook for the managed servers?
Should I put src: "//192.168.0.13/public"?
I tried also with the synchronize module but run in the same questions

Answer (score 0):

i dont think copy supports nfs stuff yet.

try mounting the nfs with [mount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mount_module.html) and then copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working via first a mount of the NFS share in the playbook.  The copy tasks executes ok according to the output but the files aren't copied over.?!

This is the copy task

```
- name: copy install files
  copy:
    src: "/mnt"
    dest: "/tmp/INSTALL_{{ ansible_fqdn }}/{{ item }}"
    group: install
    owner: setup
    mode: 0777
  with_items:
     - p1.zip
     - p2.zip
     - p3.zip
```

The folder /tmp/INSTALL_{{ ansible_fqdn }} is created but no files are copied.
With -vvv I get :

ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None

SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/setup/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r  '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "`echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480262122.31-14572056940306`" && echo ansible-tmp-1480262122.31-14572056940306="`echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1480262122.31-14572056940306`" ) && sleep 0'"'"''

Edit:

I tried it now with synchronize module

```
- name: Transfer file
  synchronize:
    src: "/IP address/oracle"
    dest: "/tmp/INSTALL_{{ ansible_fqdn }}/"
```

But then I got the following msg:

"msg": "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo\nrsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]\nrsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12)

I commented out in sudoers "# Defaults    requiretty" on both servers

Answer (score 0):

After reading through some examples, using the synchronize module is best practices I suppose.  I also messed up the syntax. The purpose of using synchronize is not deal with the hostname in src and dest. That's why this module was made. So to copy files between two remote servers we have use delegate_to.

```
 become: true
 vars:
   src: SRV1

 - name: Transfer file
   synchronize:
     src: "/setup/"
     dest: "/tmp/INSTALL_{{ ansible_fqdn }}/"
     rsync_path: "sudo rsync"
   delegate_to: "{{ src }}"
   become: no
```

When I execute the above, the 3 first tasks in the playbook execute fine. The tasks for synchronize is failing with the error below:

> UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n", "unreachable": true}

Comment: Are you sure this answers your question?

Comment: Hi Techraf, I still got a problem with getting the synchronize to work.